# Android - memory/CPU usage

Tags: android

I have two android applications that I have developed. I need to compare the two app's for a project and I am trying to find tools that will allow me to capture data about the applications such as computational use in terms of CPU/memory/data transfer etc. Also is there anyway to compare the different effects the apps would have on battery usage?

Thanks,

Comment: take a look at this :  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.burhan.cpuandmemorysttus

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For profiling CPU usage in your app (like percentage of time spend in individual methods), check out [traceview](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html). It's an executable in your tools directory that comes with the Android SDK.

For memory usage, you can use [Eclipse Memory Analyzer (MAT)](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) (there's a standalone option if you prefer another IDE).

For battery usage, there's a project called [PowerTutor](http://ziyang.eecs.umich.edu/projects/powertutor/) which helps estimate power consumed by the CPU, network interface, display, and GPS.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have looked at traceview. I was wondering if there was a tool that I could leave my app running for say 60 seconds and it would record the average CPU load during that time?

Also I have had a look at the PowerTutor but it does not seem to give a reliable log of usage over a fixed period of time for a specific app.

Answer (score 0):

In addition Qualcomm has a product for Android applications profiling, the [Trepn™ Profiler](https://developer.qualcomm.com/mobile-development/performance-tools/trepn-profiler).

From the official webpage:

> Trepn™ Profiler is a diagnostic tool that lets you profile the
>   performance and power consumption of Android applications running on
>   devices featuring Qualcomm® Snapdragon™ processors. It’s designed to
>   help you optimize your code for:
>
> ```
> CPU usage and frequency
> memory statistics (virtual and physical)
> network usage (cellular and Wi-Fi)
> ```

As the description says, it is only for **Qualcomm® Snapdragon™** processors.

Answer (score -1):

I used [Little Eye](http://www.littleeye.co/) for these purposes. It gives detailed information on power consumption, CPU load, memory and WiFi usage and generates great reports. Everything is easy, clear and convinient.

However, it can be a bit troublesome if an app loads the device very(!) heavily.