# Analyze CPU usage in android device

Tags: android, cpu-usage

It seems that my app take too much CPU for simple actions, and I want to analyze that.

How can I trace the CPU usage in android system via eclipse?
Is there any way to calculate it per method?

Comment: Did you see related answers? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118234/how-to-get-memory-usage-and-cpu-usage-in-android, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9977822/android-memory-cpu-usage ?

Comment: The first link explain how to read the cpu usage, that I dont want to. I want to analyze my app.
The second link says to view it by `traceview` that i didnt found  in eclipse

Comment: Do you mean you want your app `profiler`?

Comment: Yes, somthing that will analyze my CPU for each method.

Comment: Did you see http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.tptp.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fceproftl.xhtml?

Comment: But how can I use it with android device?

Comment: It seems requiring TPTP plugin installation. But `traceview` approach is more straighforward. `traceview` is located in `android-sdk/tools` directory (at least, in my installation).